# Programatically changing multiple UIViews in masterDetail App

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

***THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN RE-WRITTEN IN ORDER TO PROPERLY COMMUNICATE THE INTENTIONS OF THE AUTHOR***

I have a MasterDetail App that will eventually become a way to track an amount of "players" through a fixed amount of "challenges" (60 to be exact). The challenges are the same for every player, while the status of each player on the individual challenges may vary. All of the data about the players are being stored on a Postgres Database and then fetched using the JSONModel in the LeftViewController. I am getting all of the data correctly from the DB and I have successfully put it into a NSMutableDictionary. The data in the Dictionary looks like this (this is one player):

```
    player =     (
            {
        id = 9;
        name = "Arthur Dent";
        currentChallenge = "Cooking";
        timeStarted = "04 Jul 2013 1:08 PM";
        challengesDone = (
                            {
                challengeName = "Flying";
                timeCompleted = "04 Jul 2013 12:08 PM";
            }
        );
        nextChallenge = "Swimming";
        freePass =             (
            Running,
            "Climbing"
        );
    },
```

As you can see, the player has some challenges "done" ("done"), some he has doesn't need to do ("pass") on, one he is doing ("currentChallenge") and the one challenge that he will do next ("nextChallenge"). For each of these states that a player can be in, I want the "Challenges" that are in the RightViewController to be color coded so you can understand what is happening at a glance. I need the "challenges" to light up different colors, based on the status of the player, which is determined by the data that is in my NSMutableDictionary.

By creating arrays from the data in the NSDictionary I can get the colors to change by doing this:

```
if ([freePassArray containsObject:@"challenge three name"])
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"status_pass.png"]; //status_pass.png is my color
    [challengeThreeImageView setImage:image];
}
```

But if I did it like this, I would have to write 240 if and else if statements to cover all possible statuses on all 60 challenges.

My arrays only contain the data of the player selected because I pass the data over like so:

***LeftViewController.m *** didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //Re-fetch the feed from the Postgres Database when a user selects an entry

    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:@"http://myurl" completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {
    NSError* error = nil;
    _feed = [[PostgresFeed alloc] initWithDictionary:json error:&error];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:nil userInfo:[[json objectForKey:@"preclear"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}];

Player *selectedPlayer = [_players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (_delegate) 
    {
    [_delegate selectedPlayer:selectedPlayer];
    }
}
```

So the images wont set for all of the players at once, but they also do not clear after another player is selected.

How do I get the colors to change without writing 240 if and else if statements? and how would I get the colors to clear when I select another player?

Comment: just to clarify, you have a list of players, and in the detail view you have all 50 challenges. And for each user selection you want to see which of the 50 challenges are done, free, current and pass. is that correct?

Comment: @Vame Yes, I guess I could have said it like that. You are correct.

Comment: I'm confused -- what does this have to do with JSON?  You have values you want to use to control the state of certain view components.  Where the values came from is irrelevant.

Comment: @HotLicks You are correct, the JSON tag has been removed. Sorry about that.

Comment: Often about 80% of solving a problem is knowing what the question is.

Comment: @HotLicks I think I'm too stupid to know what the right question is, but if someone tells me "the answer is 42" and it works, I am happy... See above edited question. I think that by now you might know what I want to achieve. If you tell me how you would go about doing it, I'll do that and see if it works.

Comment: If you know the question you can find the answer, Grasshopper.  If you are told the answer you don't learn the question.

Comment: @HotLicks, more like FortuneCookie. Give me a bit to reformulate my question & repost...

Comment: @HotLicks Forgive me sensei, the question has been changed. Please instruct your humble pupil.

Comment: Write down the steps you'd take to do it manually, if you were essentially drawing it on a chalkboard.  Be sure to spell out exactly where each given piece of data comes from.  (As it is, it's not at all clear to us how you want to map your data to your screen.)

Comment: @HotLicks I edited my question to show how I would do this manually. also added how my data gets across. Feel free to down vote me if this is aggravating... Thank you for your help so far, I have learned much wisdom....

Comment: In your listing above, `@"challenge three name"` and `@"status_pass.png"` do not need to be literals -- they can be NSString variables.  I can't tell exactly (or even approximately) what you're doing with `freePassArray` or `challengeThreeImageView`, but those can also be "variable" in the sense that they do not always need to point to the same things.  Given that, you can easily make that code sequence a common method.  Then if you put your data into arrays, you can likely just iterate through arrays and only need one instance of that sequence (even if it's not in a method by itself).

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. Now I just need to figure out how to clear the colors when a different player is selected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have all the 50 images and you know which challenge corresponds to which image I would put the *status* image on top of the actual challenge image:

```
- (void)setChallengesDone:(NSArray*)doneAr next:(NSArray*)nextAr current:(NSArray*)currentAr andPass:(NSArray*)passAr
{
    // remove additions from the previous selected player
    UIView *prevAdditionsView = [self.view viewWithTag:122333];
    while (prevAdditionsView != nil)
    {
        [prevAdditionsView removeFromSuperview];
        prevAdditionsView = [self.view viewWithTag:122333];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<[doneAr count]; i++)
    {
        [self addChallengeImageAdditionWithImage:@"status_done" forChallenge:[doneAr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<[nextAr count]; i++)
    {
        [self addChallengeImageAdditionWithImage:@"status_next" forChallenge:[nextAr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<[currentAr count]; i++)
    {
        [self addChallengeImageAdditionWithImage:@"status_current" forChallenge:[currentAr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<[passAr count]; i++)
    {
        [self addChallengeImageAdditionWithImage:@"status_free" forChallenge:[passAr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

- (void)addChallengeImageAdditionWithImage:(NSString*)image forChallenge:(NSString*)challengeTitle
{
    UIImageView *challengeImage = [challenges objectForKey:challengeTitle];

    CGRect frame = challengeImage.frame;
    UIImageView *statusImg = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image]] autorelease];
    [statusImg setFrame:frame];
    [statusImg setAlpha:0.5]; // optionally add some transparency
    [statusImg setTag:122333];
    [self.view addSubview:statusImg];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:challengeImage]; // bring challenge image to front
}
```

The simplest way to map your challenge titles with the UIImageViews is to maintain a NSDictionary with the challenge titles as keys, and a references to their corresponding UIImageViews as values.

Comment: Trying to work this out, sorry. I guess I should also say that currently my challenges (challenge names) are actually png images that say the title of the challenge  with a frame, and the rest is transparent, and then the "statusImageView" is behind that, which will show my colors. Could you layout how I would go about making the Dictionary you mentioned? And I am guessing that the for loop would look something like `for ([notification.userinfo objectForKey:@"done"])` because all of my data is in NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *challenges; in your class, and then in view initialisation: [challenges setObject:@"Water Fight" forKey:waterFightImageView]; for putting the statusImageView behind check my edited answer.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you mean. But I don't see anyway for the above code to act upon data received from the DB. I included my DetailVC.m in the question so you can see how the data is coming in. With this in mind, How would I go about implementing your code above? I don't have a class for Players or Challenges, so creating the Dictionary becomes interesting. Forgive me if this is becoming to dull, I am still coming to grips with this language.

Comment: I changed the question. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: You click the Player on the left, you get the JSON showed above, you parse it, and you have 4 arrays of strings (challenge names for current, next, done, and free). you pass those arrays in the function i wrote you and voila. That requires from you to create the Dictionary with the mapping of challenge title/challenge UIImageView in the initial creation of the detailViewController. That's all

Comment: Thank you for your help and time. This does not work. I have edited my question to show how I am currently doing it. Feel free to down vote if needed.

Comment: @CaptJak I cannot test it cause i don' have your project's source. Could you tell me which exact point doesn't work? first of all, have you tried to store your UIImageView references into a NSDictionary?

Comment: HA!combined efforts will prevail! I used a lot of your code and got the colors working, but now they won't go away when I pick another person. Is there a way to just tell a UIImage view to trash the image it currently has? I could do that before loading the rest of the player data.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent example of the model/view concept.

- Each challenge is a model with all the info required (challenge name, status, timestamp and others).
- Each of your 50 views is a "challenge view" that knows how to render any challenge.
- The status *data* is in the model; the status *image* is in the view.

Example:

```
-(void) drawChallenge: (Challenge*) challenge
{
    // Draw challenge name as text
    switch ([challenge status])
    {
        case done: // draw "done" image
        case next: // draw "next" image
    }
}
```

The idea is that the challenge *itself* should not know about how it is rendered, and the view should not know about what the challenge contains. The view is responsible for drawing it.

This could be packed into a ChallengeView subclass of UIView. Then, create your 50 or so ChallengeViews, and call [currentView drawChallenge: currentChallenge].

Essentially, when a new challenge is added, you create a view for it, and give the view a pointer to the challenge. When the challenge view is rendered by iOS, it'll draw "its" challenge as you have described in the drawChallenge method.

If you need a primer on the Model-View-Controller pattern, [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) of the Apple docs is pretty good. You can disregard the Controller role in this situation.